# Spring binding errors: display only some messages in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In a JSP I'm listing all the binding/validation errors together:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
        <li><c:out value="${error}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>    
</ul>
```

However, I have some custom behavior and would like to ignore all the "typeMismatch" errors. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
<c:if test="${not error.isTypeMismatch}">
    <li><c:out value="${error}"/></li>
</c:if>
```

Since ${error} is just a plain old String, I don't know how I could determine something like this.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: can we check for the substring and proceed? like.. if(error.search("Type Mismatch")>0) .. etc?

Answer (score 0):

Since errors are just strings, I don't see a way to separate type mismatch errors from others other then checking if the error actually contains some text expected to be in type mismatch errors.

```
${not error.contains('[some type mismatch text]')}
```